# Typescript switch statement not working properly

Tags: javascript, typescript

For some reason this switch is not reaching any of the cases defined

```
const resultList = ['pass', 'fail', 'skip']
        for(const result in resultList){
            try {
                const endpoint = 'www.url.com';
                const response = await axios.get(endpoint);
                console.log(endpoint, response)
                if(response.status == 200){
                    console.log('status code good')
                    switch(result){
                        case 'pass':
                            console.log('case = pass');
                            this.passed = response.data;
                            break;
                        case 'fail':
                            console.log('case = fail');

                            this.failed = response.data;
                            break;
                        case 'skip':
                            console.log('case = skip');

                            this.skipped = response.data;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
```

I am seeing 200 responses from the API, however I never see any of the case logs... what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: what do you see when you debug the code?

Comment: the console prints the endpoint, the response object. it also prints 'status code good' so I know the switch statement is expected, however it never prints any of the statements within the switch cases

Comment: You should be using a for-of loop not for-in. Using for-in on an array only gives you the indices (1, 2, 3, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for...in` loop iterate over the keys in a list, in this case:

```js
const resultList = ['pass', 'fail', 'skip']
for(const result in resultList){ 
  console.log(result)
}
```

Will print

```
0
1
2
```

And for this, the condition on the switch fails.

To iterate over the values of a list, use the `for...of` loop.

```js
for(const result of resultList) { ... }
```